# Linphone server developer manual

Tags: asterisk, voip, linphone

I am currently playing around with the open source VOIP, and I found linphone. However I wanna set my own asterisk server for the Linphone and test. But I cannot find any source talking about the Linphone server yet. Then do you have the developer manual or document for Linphone server ? If you have could you please share me ?

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend throwing linphone over board, also tried it out and it made me bite my keyboard. Set up an asterisk server and take a look at pjsip, an Softphone C-Library. This might take while, but then you have a good and solid solution.